# Есть ли онлайн конвертер с jquery на vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, я бэкенд разработчик и немного знаю jquery, но совсем не знаю vanilla js и мне нужно этот код переписать в чистый js

```
$(document).on("change", ".custom-file-input", function(){
    let fileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
    $(this).next('.custom-file-label').addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

Есть ли какой нибудь онлайн конвертер? Не могу найти, а переписать не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Да, есть](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20jquery%20to%20javascript%20online&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk001MXHFu8cpPxG_Xj5uvxnWo409JA%3A1615835904201&ei=ALNPYOa8C62yrgT105HgAg&oq=converter%20Jquery%20to%20javascript&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYATIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIGCAAQBRAeOgcIABBHELADOgUIABDNAjoGCAAQBxAeOggIABAHEAUQHjoGCAAQCBAeOgQIABANOggIABAIEAcQHlCMHlixVWCRZGgBcAF4AIABiAKIAecQkgEGMC4xMi4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz), но они не всегда приводят рабочий код - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1256355/221218)

---

> .. мне нужно этот код переписать в чистый js

Вроде как логика та же..

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('custom-file-input')) {
    let fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    let next = nextByClass(e.target, '.custom-file-label');
    next.classList.add('selected');
    next.innerHTML = fileName;
  }
});

// Поиск следующего элемента по классу.
function nextByClass(node, cls) {
  while(node = node.nextSibling)
    if(` ${node.className} `.indexOf(` ${cls} `) != -1) return node;
  return null;
}
```

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, спасибо, исправил. Функцию ещё одну потерял))

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос, так как спрашивали про онлайн-конвертер...

Comment: @andreymal, я один вижу чёткий вопрос **`..мне нужно этот код переписать в чистый js`**, в добавок есть ещё [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1256355/221218), где видно что код "перевдён" через "конвертер" да ещё и с ошибкой.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 то есть чёткий вопрос «Есть ли какой нибудь онлайн конвертер?» вы серьёзно не увидели в тексте?

Comment: @andreymal, окей, оформлю по вашему.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я не уверен, что на этот вопрос вообще следовало бы отвечать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Есть. Я искал по словам **jquery to javascript converter online**. Сразу куча ссылок.

**[Один из них](https://properprogramming.com/tools/jquery-to-javascript-converter/)** выдал вот такое:

```
document.querySelector(document).addEventListener("change", ".custom-file-input", function(){
    let fileName = document.querySelector(this).value.split('\').pop();
    document.querySelector(this).next('.custom-file-label').classList.add("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

---

В целом есть **[шпаргалка](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/wiki/Converting-jQuery-to-JavaScript)** по переводу

Comment: Вот мне интересно. Куча ссылок ответ и все такое. За 1 минуту. Супермен одним словом

Comment: И конечно. ТП зарегистрирован сегодня под ником Volan de mort

Comment: @AzizUmarov ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AzizUmarov а ещё параллельно конвертирую картинки в читаемые pdf)))  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYgJF.png

Comment: Просто мне  новички попадаются которые вопрос оформить не могут не говоря о стилях и прочих

Comment: А перевод, кстати, неверный) JS не съест делегирование в виде аргумента `".custom-file-input"`. Есть еще http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, не работает

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ну, просили конвертер))  Полагаю должно быть так `document.addEventListener...` ?)

Comment: Полагаю должно было быть. document.querySelector('.custom-file-input').addEventListener ("change", function ...)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, и не только) В буквальном переводе - https://jsfiddle.net/sumvayp5/3/

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME жаль))